# ArcMap ModelBuilder: Have iterator run only once to test model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator

I am working on building a model in ArcMap 10.4.1 ModelBuilder. This particular model iterates through rows of a table, running a series of processes/tools on each row. [image: Model screenshot] Since there are 50+ rows in this initial table, it takes some time to iterate through each row and run the entire model.

As I am adding new elements on to the end, I would like to be able to test the model by running through **only the first row**, to see if the elements I've added are functioning properly. Is there a way to tell the "Iterate Row Selection" tool I only want to run the model using the first row to test things out?

I know I can start the model and simply cancel it once the first iteration has completed, but I am wondering if there is a neater or proper way to do this. My apologies if this question has been asked before or has an obvious answer, I've tried my best to find an answer and haven't been successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export one row of your table and use that in your model, or, instead of iterating over that original table, use a selection tool.

Comment: Ah, of course! I was imagining a built-in setting for the iterator that could do this, but excellent idea. I just put in a selection tool to find those with ID < 4 to try out the model on my first three rows.

Answer (score 4):

Put a definition query on the table where ObjectID < 1, then with the table open, run the model.